# Ubuntu installed but windows subsystem for linux has no installed distributions

Tags: 18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed ubuntu 18.04 manually (because my Microsoft Store doesn't work), now ubuntu is default OS. I then switched to Windows and opened cmd (I tried cmd in normal as well as admin mode) and ran `wsl` (my computer can only support wsl1) but i am getting the error:

```
C:\Users\Lenovo>wsl
Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.
Distributions can be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store:
https://aka.ms/wslstore
```

However, virtual machine is enabled and wsl is also turned on (through "Turn Windows features On or Off"). How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WSL (especially WSL version 1) installations **prefer** the Microsoft Store to function properly, as they install special inside the Windows environment.  WSL2 uses a hypervisor layer within Windows to run Linux, but for the most part it utilizes Windows' installation tools and mechanisms on the Microsoft Store to deploy in a way that is compatible.  What you've done is a dual boot, NOT installing to the OS like you did.  There's a separate app install process.

---

**What you did is a Dual Boot, not a WSL install.**

If you did a dual boot like you did, WSL can't access the dualboot.  The dual boot is installed directly to disk in partitions and filesystems that Windows will not be able to read - as such, you cannot use WSL to access the Dual Boot.

Dual Boot is also not WSL - it's an actual on-disk installation side by side with Windows as its own entity and **not** part of Windows or WSL.

If you intend to use Ubuntu then while in a dual boot configuration like this, just use Ubuntu directly and boot to Windows or Ubuntu selectively at your leisure.  Ubuntu can access/read information in Windows partitions (if you disable Fast Boot in Windows), but Windows will be unable to read Ubuntu's data.

---

**Microsoft DOES provide manual steps here to install the WSL, though it's still slightly dependent on downloading the items from Microsoft as 'apps' locally without the Store.**

The way to do the WSL Manual Installation is with this data from Microsoft - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual - with the following PowerShell steps (the example uses 16.04 on Microsoft's site, but I will use the 20.04 links):

1. Download the distro for WSL in Powershell

   ```
   Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/wslubuntu2004 -OutFile Ubuntu.appx -UseBasicParsing
   ```
2. Install the distro - it's an appx file so you need to use PowerShell to install it in WSL

   ```
   Add-AppxPackage .\Ubuntu.appx
   ```

This should do the WSL install.  Then, you have two more potential steps to do:

- [Update the system from WSL1 to WSL2 (optional)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#set-your-distribution-version-to-wsl-1-or-wsl-2)
- [Create a new user account and password for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/user-support)

Comment: Your first paragraph is incorrect, WSL is not dependant on MS Store -  MS provides instructions of how to download/install various WSL distros manually without using MS Store - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual.

Comment: @NGRhodes my Google fu with Microsoft must be reduced heh.  I searched for something like that, didn't find it.  I took your link and adjusted the answer now.